# Best way to store OAuth access token from Authorization Code flow

Tags: api, server, web-applications, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm making a Node.js web application that primarily uses an API to fetch data from a user who accepts the OAuth login for the API (Authorization Code Flow).

**After receiving an access token from the authorization server to my web server through OAuth Authorization Code Flow, I was wondering what was the best way to store this data efficiently?**

The token has an expiration time of an hour, and I'm also given a refresh token with the package.

I want to: **1. not have to use my database to store the access token, 2. possibly be able to keep the person logged in whenever they come back.**

I thought about cookies/sessions, but that requires storing data in my DB, and I feel like that might be a little redundant for my application, as it's going to constantly be using the user's access token, and the token has a short life span. I've also thought about storing the access token in a JWT too, but I've read that that's insecure.

I'm a beginner developer, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Store the refresh token there is no reason to store anything else.

Comment: But then how do I remember that specific users access token for usage

Comment: you would need to store the refresh token and associate it with the user on your system.  Then when ever that user comes back you can use their refresh token to get a new access token and access their data.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo "Store the refresh token there is no reason to store anything else.", you are suggesting the access token should be thrown away? What is the point of the access token at that point? You would have to contact the identity provider with the refresh token every time the user would make a request that requires authentication with that setup, which would be very inefficient. The entire point of the access token is that that's not necessary.

Comment: access tokens expire after 1 hour there is no need to store them for future use.   Store the refresh token and then you can request a new access token when ever you need.    The point of an access token is to give you limited time access to private user data.   Access tokens are needed to request access from APIs.